# HTML5 Canvas Grid - Get Grid Square Size From Input

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How can I get the value of the input and turn it into the size of the grid squares? When I use the input value, my grid is messed up, but when I hard code the grid square size it works fine.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/NbqKMQ

and here is the code:

```
// get our canvas 
var grid = document.getElementById('grid');
hide(grid);

var horizontalSpace = 0;
var verticalSpace = 0;

var button = document.getElementById('gridControls');
button.onclick = drawCanvas;


function drawCanvas() {

show(grid);
var context = grid.getContext('2d');

// HERE: Why doesn't this work???
// var gridSize = document.getElementById('widthHeight').value;
var gridSize = 10;

// set the canvas style to positions absolute
// and set z-index high to keep it on top
grid.style.position = 'absolute';
grid.style.zIndex = '100000';

// get window width and height
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

// set the canvas width and height to be the window w/h
grid.width = w;
grid.height = h;

// create the horizontal lines
for(var horizontal = 0; horizontal < w; horizontal++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, horizontalSpace);
    context.lineTo(w, horizontalSpace);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "lightblue";
    context.stroke();
    horizontalSpace += gridSize;
}

// create the vertical lines
for(var vertical = 0; vertical < h; vertical++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(verticalSpace, 0);
    context.lineTo(verticalSpace, h);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "lightblue";
    context.stroke();
    verticalSpace += gridSize;
}

}

function hide(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

function show(element) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Try uncommenting the line where I try to set gridSize as the value of the input field and see the result. It messes up the grid spaces!

Any idea how to remedy this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it: I need to use parseInt() on the value.